# Как различать объекты в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Я могу повеcить слушатель на RecyclerView но тогда все предметы будут выполнять одинаковые команды, мне надо чтобы отдельный объект выполнял отдельную команду

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы например объект 1 писал в лог хай, а обьект 2 писал бай. Они всегда в случайном порядке

Comment: если нужно на парный item повесить другое действие то это по позишну определять нужно будет, если же у вас действие зависит от контента item-a то нужно добавлять в него еще какие-то данные чтобы проверять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь к модели item tag и дай каждому значение, но по любому ты должен делатъ проверки.

Comment: Не подскажете как?

Comment: ты создал класс Модели для item а RecyclerVIew ? к примеру class LentaModel

Comment: в этом классе добавь к примеру int tag; со своими гетерами и сетерами, присвой к каждому какое нибудь число, можно позицию в листе, и потом уже получай в нужном месте и проверяй

Comment: я добавляю так couponss.add(new Coupons(R.drawable.petiarochka));

Comment: класс с сеттерами и геттерами у меня есть

Comment: Ну вот, Добавь в классе Coupons int tag; 
затем туда где добавляешь;
Coupons coupon = new Coupons(R.drawable.petirochka);
coupon.setTag = position;
couponss.add(coupon);

проверка и комада:
if(coupon.getTag == position){ //do work}